# Custom property of a UIView used in Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, interface-builder

I know that could be done, but I can't remember how.

I would like to create some properties of a view and been able to change this in interface builder. Also I would like that after I specify the class of the UIView that this view is rendered correctly in interface builder.

Can someone help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subclass your UIView as you usually would to extend the functionality. The two unique portions of code are `@IBDesignable` which enables the live rendering in Interface Builder and `@IBInspectable` which will surface the appropriate properties in Interface Builder.

```
@IBDesignable class NewView: UIView {
     // Display New Color as an editable property in Interface Builder.
     @IBInspectable var newColor: UIColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

You can then do any required drawing by overriding the `drawRect(rect: CGRect)` function using any newly provided properties.